# How to customize folder name when compilemessages in website insternationalization

Tags: django, internationalization

For website Internationalization when run this command

```
django-admin compilemessages -l de
```

it produce the .po file under the locale folder like 
           `locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`
I want to rename **LC_MESSAGES**
How can I do this ???
Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You should add a code snippet to rename the directory, this is the hard way but unfortunately, I don't know a better one.

```
import os
basedir = 'locale/de/' # Or you should add something like C:/locale/de
newname = 'Your script'
os.rename(os.path.join(basedir, newname)
```